# Cypress test not fails if test starts with Cypress.Promise

Tags: javascript, cypress, request-promise

I am having issue when running test on Cypress.

My test function following is failing but the test status is passed. This happens if the test test starts with Cypress.Promise command. Could you please help?

```
it('waiting for answer', () => {
        new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
            resolve('ok')
        }).then((question) => {
            cy.get('x')
        })
    })
```

[image]

Note: it is working truly if the test not stars with Cypress.Promise command like below.

```
it('waiting for answer', () => {
        cy.request('www.google.com').then((response) => {
            new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
                resolve('ok')
            }).then((question) => {
                cy.get('x')
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: I think you have to return that promise

Comment: @Konrad not worked :(

Comment: Why do you need a Promise? Usually you don't need to make Promises in Cypress because (almost) everything returns a promise by default